# Elasticsearch exact matches when query text is a substring

Tags: elasticsearch, exact-match

I have data in my Elasticsearch with a field

```
PUT /logs/visited_domains/1
{
"visited_domain":"microsoft.com"
}
PUT /logs/visited_domains/2
{
"visited_domain":"not-microsoft.com"
}
```

The mapping is:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "visited_domain": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

When I do an ElasticSearch of

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "visited_domain": "microsoft.com"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I will get both results.  But I only want the exact match.  Any ideas of how I alter the query or improve the mapping?

**EDIT:**  I changed one of my examples from `notmicrosoft.com` to `not-microsoft.com` because this dash is causing alot of the trouble.  `notmicrosoft.com` does not return, but `not-microsoft.com` does, when searching for `microsoft.com`.

Answer (score 4):

Use query_string which gives exact match when used with quotes

```
 "query": {
     "query_string": {
          "default_field": "visited_domain",
                "query": "\"microsoft.com\""
                }
  }
```

Comment: I managed to solve my exact problem using this method. I am unsure though on how to include the quotes if my query is a variable instead.